# How to store the output of an XMLHttpRequest in a global variable

Tags: javascript, json

I have a webpage that will load a couple `JSON` files via `XMLHttpRequest`.
I want to load the file, parse the `JSON` and store the output in a globally accessible variable.
Once BOTH `foo` and `bar` are complete, only then do I want to call the `success()` function.  So far, my script has 2 problems that I need help with.

1: I'm having trouble setting the variable to the output of `loadJSON()`. My guess is that my return statements are a little funky?  I've tried everything... help?

2: How do I call `success()` only AFTER BOTH `foo` and `bar` are set?

```
var foo;
var bar;

function initSession(){

    foo = loadJSON("foo.js");
    bar = loadJSON("bar.js");

}
```

My guess is that the problem lies in how I'm using return in the `loadJSON()` function:

```
function loadJSON(url){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){  
            return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);  // doesn't work?
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();

    return xhr.onreadystatechange;
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    initSession();
});


function success(){ 
    $("body").append(foo[0]);  
    $("body").append(bar[0]);  
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The `return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` is not working because it's asynchronous and you can assign the result into a global var in that callback function usinf `varname = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` but this may not solve the problem.

Comment: so how can I call success() only after BOTH foo and bar are set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who discovers this in the future... below was my final solution based on the discussion in the accepted answer. which would easily allow an extension to dynamically set the number of files before the success function is called.

```
var foo;
var bar;
var count = 0;

function initSession(){

    loadJSON("foo.js", "foo");
    loadJSON("bar.js", "bar");   

}

function loadJSON(url, name){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){  
            count++;
            window[name] = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);;

            if (count == 2){
                success();
            } 
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    initSession();
});



function success(){ 
    $("body").append(foo[0].option + "<br>" + bar[0].fname + " " + bar[0].lname);  
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)

Comment: Any way, It does not work for me! I just replaced the URLs, and still the result is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadJSON("foo.js");
    loadJSON("bar.js");
});
```

Modify your `success` function:

```
function success(data){ 
    $("body").append(data[0]);  
}
```

Then modify in your `success callback/onreadystatechange`

```
if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){  
    success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
}
```

Call the `success` function from `success callback/onreadystatechange` function. Also you can pass a callback function to `loadJSON` function and can call that `callback` function from the `onreadystatechange/success callback`, for example:

```
function loadJSON(url, callback){

    // ...

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){  
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you may pass the callback function like this:

```
loadJSON("foo.js", function(data){
    // do something with data
});
```

So, you can use different callback functions for different `ajax` requests.

Comment: yes, this works... but the idea is that I don't want to load success until BOTH foo and bar have reached a readyState of 4...

Comment: The `success` global function will be called once at a time after the data is returned, so there would be no problem.

Comment: I think I might not be understanding you properly... i don't want to call success once at a time. I only want to call it once.  after loadJSON() is complete for both files.

Comment: [Check this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Comment: Actually `success` will be called every time the ajax request succeeded and data returned from the server, so `success` will be called twice for two `ajax` requests. So the `$("body").append(data[0]);` will be executed only when data is returned from the server.

Comment: If you want to call the success only once then instead of calling the success from the `onreadystatechange` you may keep/store the returned response to a variable and on the second successful `ajax` call, call the `success` function.

Comment: that's a great point to count the number of success callbacks!  i'm trying that now

Comment: Adding a callback to loadJSON() is a good idea.. but your previous suggestion to count the successes worked for me!

Comment: I've accepted your answer. thanks! but - i added my final solution as another answer.  thanks for your help!